# Mapping between ids and indices using numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working on a graphical application that uses shapes such as quads, trias, lines etc. to represent geometry.

The input data is based on ID's. 
 A list of points is provided, each with an ID and coordinates (x, y, z)
 A list of shapes is provided, each defined using the ids from he list of points

So a tria is defined as N1, N2, N3 where the N's are ID's in the list of points

I'm using VTK to display the data and it uses indices and not ids.

So I have to convert the id based input to index based input and I use the following numpy array approach which works REALLY well (and was provided by someone on this board I think)

```
# nodes  - numpy array of point ids
nodes=np.asarray([1, 15, 56, 101, 150])  # This array can be millions of ids long

nmx = nodes.max() 
node_id_to_index = np.empty((nmx + 1,), dtype=np.uint32)

# Using the node id as an index, insert consecutive indices as values into the array
# This gives us an array that can be indexed by ID and return the compact index
node_id_to_index[nodes] = np.arange(len(nodes), dtype=np.uint32)
```

Now when I have a shape defined using ids I can easily convert it to use indices like this

```
elems_by_id = np.asarray([56,1,150,15,101,1]) # This array can be millions of ids long
elems_by_index = node_id_to_index[elems_by_id]

# gives [2, 0, 4, 1, 3, 0]
```

One weakness of the approach is that if the original list of ids contains even a VERY large number, I'm required to allocate an array big enough to hold that many items. Even though I may not have that many entries in the original id list. (The original ID list can have gaps in the ids). I ran into this condition today.....

So my question is - how can I modify this approach to handle lists that contain ids so large that I don't have enough memory to create the mapping array?

Any help will be gratefully received....

Doug

OK - I think I found a solution - Credit to @Paul Panzer

But first some addition info - the input nodes array is sorted and guaranteed to  have only unique ids

```
elems_by_index = nodes.searchsorted(elems_by_id)
```

This is only marginally slower than the original approach - so I'll just branch based on the max id in nodes - use the original approach when I can easily allocate enough memory and the second approach when the max id is huge....

Comment: you can work with a remapping of your indices, from `np.unique(nodes)` to `np.arange(len(np.unique(nodes)))`

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the arrays?

Comment: @Alexander Cecil - Added the array contents

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, essentially you're looking for a fast way to find the index of a number in a list, e. g., you have a list like:

```
nodes = [932, 578, 41, ...]
```

and need a structure that would give

```
id_to_index[932] == 0
id_to_index[578] == 1
id_to_index[41]  == 2
# etc.
```

(which can be done with something as simple as `nodes.index(932)`, except that wouldn't be any fast). And your current solution is, essentially, the first part of the [pigeonhole sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort) algorithm, and the problem is that the "number of elements (n) and the length of the range of possible key values (N) are approximately the same" condition isn't met - the range is much bigger in your case, so too much memory is wasted on that auxiliary data structure.

Why not simply use a Python dictionary, by the way? E. g. `id_to_index = {932: 0, 578: 1, 41: 2, ...}` - is it too slow (your current lookup is O(1), with a dictionary it would be log something)? Or is it because you want numpy indexing (e. g. `id_to_index[[n1, n2, n3]]` instead of one by one)? Perhaps, then, you can use [SciPy sparce matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) (a single-row matrix instead of an array):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

nodes = np.array([9, 2, 7]) # a small test sample

# your solution with a numpy array
nmx = nodes.max()
node_id_to_index = np.empty((nmx + 1,), dtype=np.uint32)
node_id_to_index[nodes] = np.arange(len(nodes), dtype=np.uint32)

elems_by_id = [7, 2] # an even smaller test sample
elems_by_index = node_id_to_index[elems_by_id]

# gives [2 1]
print(elems_by_index)

# same with a 1 by (nmx + 1) sparce matrix
m = sp.csr_matrix((1, nmx + 1), dtype = np.uint32)   # 1 x 10 matrix, stores nothing
m[0, nodes] = np.arange(len(nodes), dtype=np.uint32) # 1 x 10 matrix, stores 3 elements
m_by_index = m[0, elems_by_id]                       # looking through the 0-th row
print(m_by_index.toarray()[0])                       # also gives [2 1]
```

Not sure if I chose the optimal type of matrix for this, read the descriptions of different types of sparse matrix formats to find the best one for the task.

Comment: Python Dictionaries are too slow and I need the numpy indexing - I have to convert entire arrays of id's to indices - ranging in size form a handful of ids to potentially millions of ids. I'll take a look at the SciPy sparse matrix - I haven't used these before